# What is the fastest Redundancy Checksum in C# for a string?

Tags: c#, checksum, crc, crc32

I have a string, 20-30 characters long, contains case sensitive letters and numbers

I need to generate a 2 chars checksum (in cased sensitive letters and numbers as well)

and put them together for an unique id

What is the fastest method in C# to calculate a checksum for verification purpose?

Comment: Checksums generally *aren't* unique, and certainly if you're wanting a 32-bit integer, you won't get a unique one for 30 characters...

Comment: ...and a 2-char checksum is going to have even higher probability of collision: "case sensitive letters and numbers" will give you 62 possible characters (assuming the English alphabet); two of those characters enables 62*62=3844 possible combinations - equivalent to slightly less than a 12 bit number!

Comment: so if my string is 25 chars, how many chars extra checksum is good? 5^=916 132 832, is this good? but anyway, is CRC32 ok for this? I read crc32 code, seems it gives a 32bit number

Comment: You can represent 5 bits with a single character using your charset. In order to represent a full 32-bit checksum, you need 7 extra characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problems:

1. *Fast checksum calculation for a string*: Adler32 is fast enough with good enough distribution for it's speed.
2. *Converting checksum into a string of your character set (case sensitive letters + numbers)*: If you could add `+` and `/` characters, you could easily use base64
3. *Generating a unique ID from those two*: This is just impossible with given method. Because you'll end up with same checksum for same string, which doesn't help uniqueness.

What you can do there is to use a global counter if your item set is limited and increment it everytime you create a new record.

Comment: What I mean is, I will generate a unique long string, then add checksum at the end. So I can do a simple checksum before doing database check. I will take a look on the Adler32, thanks